# How should I start answering this chemical substance question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

Two  substances,  A  and  B,  are  being  converted  into  a  single  compound C. In  the  laboratory  it  has  been  shown  that,  for  these  substances,  the following  law  of  conversion  holds:    the  time  rate  of  change  of  the amount x of compound C is proportional to the product of the amounts of unconverted substances A & B.  If at time t = 0 there are C<sub>AO</sub> mols/li of substance A and C<sub>BO</sub> mols of substance B, and none of compound C present,  find  x(t).    Assume  that  1  mole  of  C  is  formed  from  the combination of 1 mole of A and one mole of B.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/84059/30836

Answer (score 1):

Start by setting up equations.

I prefer to write  $A_0$ and $B_0$ for $C_{AO}$ and $C_{BO}$, respectively, and $C$ for $x$.

$\dfrac{dC}{dt}=-\dfrac{dA}{dt}=-\dfrac{dB}{dt}=kAB$

$A+C=A_0$

$B+C=B_0$

Therefore $\dfrac{dC}{dt}=k(A_0-C)(B_0-C)=k(A_0B_0-(A_0+B_0)C+C^2)$.

This is a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) differential equation, which can be solved with standard methods.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @J. W. Tanner's answer, the easy way to solve
$$\dfrac{dC}{dt}=k(A_0-C)(B_0-C)$$ is to write it as
$$\dfrac{dt}{dC}=\frac 1{k(A_0-C)(B_0-C)}=\frac{1}{k (A_0-B_0)}\left( \frac 1{C-A_0}- \frac 1{C-B_0}\right)$$ which gives (since $C_0=0$
$$t =\frac{1}{k (A_0-B_0)}\,\log \left(\frac{C-A_0}{C-B_0}\right)$$ from which it is easy to express $C(t)$.